# Modify/configure log4php LoggerLayoutHtml to insert <BR> tags

Tags: html, logging, log4php

Sorry, rather obscure... but there doesn't appear to be a log4php forum.

I just want to log a string and for the newlines to be output in the HTML log as <br>.  Trouble is, even if you use PHP's nl2br, it appears the logger reconverts back to the artefacts (or whatever the word is)... i.e. the logger converts "<br>" to "&lt;br&gt;" before outputting to the HTML file.

I don't know whether you can configure LoggerLayoutHtml to do this (clean, nice solution) or whether I will have to do some (dirty) tweaking of the code in the PHP files of log4php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyone interested in a quick and dirty solution:

in the file LoggerLayoutHtml.php under log4php:

replace the line

```
$sbuf .= htmlentities($event->getRenderedMessage(), ENT_QUOTES);
```

with this:

```
    $rendered_msg = htmlentities( $event->getRenderedMessage(), ENT_QUOTES );
    $sbuf .= nl2br( $rendered_msg );
```